# Get view name URL (.aspx) CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

This code i see only view title, but i need name view to URL (.aspx):

```
var viewCollection = null;
    function runCode() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var web = clientContext.get_web();
            var listCollection = web.get_lists();
            var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Test");
            this.viewCollection = list.get_views();
            var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
            viewInfo.set_title();
            this.viewCollection.add(viewInfo);
            clientContext.load(this.viewCollection);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    }
function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var viewInfo = 'Tasks list current views: \n\n';
        var viewEnumerator = this.viewCollection.getEnumerator();
        while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
            viewInfo += view.get_title() + '\n';
                 alert(view.get_title());
                    }
                }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL via *view.get_serverRelativeUrl()*:

Here is the updated code:

```
var viewCollection = null;

function runCode() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var listCollection = web.get_lists();
        var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Test");
        this.viewCollection = list.get_views();
        var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
        viewInfo.set_title();
        this.viewCollection.add(viewInfo);
        clientContext.load(this.viewCollection);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var viewInfo = 'Tasks list current views: \n\n';
    var viewEnumerator = this.viewCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
        viewInfo += view.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '\n';
        alert(view.get_serverRelativeUrl());
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very much, that is my mistake, i'm not develop in visual studio, of course intellisense not can see.